# How to unite two integers in C

Tags: c

I have a problem that uniting two integers.
I want to unite two integers. For example;

```
int x[4]={5,3,6,7};

printf("%d", x[0]x[1]+x[2]x[3]);
```

So, what I want to do is;

```
printf("%d", 53+67);
```

In a nutshell I want to get 120.

It should be capable of doing this;

```
printf("%d", 764+7);
```

I mean, the digits are changeable it can be 654+6 or 56+65 or 2+678756875.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why the 3 downvotes? This is clearly a noob's question, isn't it?

Comment: For your extra examples, what is the input?  How do you know how the digits are supposed to be grouped?  (For example, if the input is `int x[4] = { 6, 5, 4, 6 };`, and that's to be treated as 654+6 = 660, how do you know that the first three digits are part of one number and the last digit is the only digit of another.  But with luck, that's not the representation you've actually got.) You're likely to need to write a function to do the summing, which will likely be based on a loop calculating `10 * sum_so_far + x[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

Um, `x[0]*10 + x[1] + x[2]*10 + x[3]`?

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("%d", (10*x[0]+x[1]) + (10*x[2]+x[3]));
```

Comment: The question has been extended without sufficient explanation. This answers the original question, but the extended question is as yet ill-defined (the inputs are undefined).

Answer (score 0):

Use basic arithmetic:

```
printf("%d\n", x[0]*10 + x[1] + x[2]*10 + x[3]);
```

Anything in the hundreds digit place should be multiplied by 100; anything in the tens digit place should be multiplied by 10; etc.